# "Export as Swagger" and "Export as Swagger + Postman" from API gateway is missing 'parameters' object

Tags: amazon-web-services, export, postman, aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0

I have an API gateway endpoint (/item/{itemId}) with a path parameter 'itemId' in it. Here's the swagger definition I used to create the endpoint in API gateway.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "sample-postman-import"
  },
  "host": "example.com",
  "basePath": "/api",
  "schemes": ["https"],
  "paths": {
    "/item/{itemId}": {
      "get": {
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "itemId",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response"
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

After deploying the API, when I export it as a swagger definition, the exported definition is missing the 'parameters' object, making it an incomplete swagger file. I've seen the same issue when I

1. Tried exporting from the UI as shown in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html
2. Used the getExport API call from javascript aws-sdk https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#getExport-property

Here's what the export looks like:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "sample-postman-import_old"
  },
  "host": "example.com",
  "basePath": "/api",
  "schemes": ["https"],
  "paths": {
    "/item/{itemId}": {
      "get": {
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response"
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue when I have created my API Gateway with Terraform. On the AWS UI the parameter was shown but when I requested method information through the AWS CLI with `aws apigateway get-method` command the parameter was not provided. So make sure you have the "requestParameters" set as you want and if not, set it through the CLI or Terraform.